# Why is this returning null when the string is being set inside the methods that parse the JSON? (Bottom returns are all null)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to use an API to pull data and put it into TextViews inside of a fragment. I already can get the data from JSON fine but when trying to return the values they are null.

```
public class Handler {
String pName;
String pPosition;
String pTeam;
String pDivision;
String pConf;

//getName gets the players first and last name concats them and returns the string
public String getName(String nameJsonStr) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject nameJSONObj = new JSONObject(nameJsonStr);
    String fullName = (nameJSONObj.getString("first_name")) + " " + (nameJSONObj.getString("last_name"));
    pName = fullName;
    return pName;
}

//gets the player's position from JSON
public String getPosition(String positionJsonStr) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject positionJSONObj = new JSONObject(positionJsonStr);
    pPosition = positionJSONObj.getString("position");
    return pPosition;
}

//gets player's team from JSON
public String getTeam(String teamJsonStr) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject teamJSONObj = new JSONObject(teamJsonStr);
    pTeam = teamJSONObj.getJSONObject("team").getString("full_name");
    return pTeam;
}

//gets player's division from JSON
public String getDivision(String divisionJsonStr) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject divisionJSONObj = new JSONObject(divisionJsonStr);
    pDivision = divisionJSONObj.getJSONObject("team").getString("division");
    return pDivision;
}

//gets player's conference from JSON
public String getConference(String conferenceJsonStr) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject conferenceJSONObj = new JSONObject(conferenceJsonStr);
    pConf = conferenceJSONObj.getJSONObject("team").getString("conference");
    return pConf;
}

public String getpName(){return pName;}
public String getpPosition(){return pPosition;}
public String getpTeam(){return pTeam;}
public String getpDivision(){return pDivision;}
public String getpConf(){return pConf;}
}
```

These should be returning stored values from the JSON getters

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the methods that are setting your variables.

When you write

```
 public String getpName(){return pName;}
```

you're returning the uninitialized instance variable (pName) from the top of your script:

```
 String pName;
```

Un-Initialized String instance variables default to null (String pName = null)

Instead you need to modify your code like this:

```
 public String getpName(String nameJsonStr){
    // return the value returned by getName()
    return getName(nameJsonStr);//pass in the nameJsonStr to the getName() method
 }
```